# Can't login in YouTube: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: youtube

Since about last Friday I can't login in YouTube. I've tried to fix it by cleaning the cache and the cookies, but the error shows up every time I login.

If I go to the home page in incognito mode I can see it, but if I try to login I see the error again.

The error message is:

> **500 Internal Server Error**
>
> Sorry, something went wrong.
>
> A team of highly trained monkeys has been dispatched to deal with this situation.
>
> If you see them, show them this information:
>
> AB38WEMGwsoXEupT... ...

Already tried logging in with Firefox and Chrome and it shows the error in any of this browsers. If I login with a different account (Google Apps) all works fine fine.

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions installed? Try disabling them.

Comment: Also try with a different browser.

Comment: I have the same problem with Firefox (I was using Chrome before), all extensions are disabled and I did after deleting the cookies and the cache.

Comment: check for proxy

Comment: Thanks @Neo Surprisingly it works fine if I login with my Google Apps account...

Answer (score 1):

`500 Internal Server Error` means just that: Something went wrong on the server-side, not your fault. Waiting for a day or so typically solves it, if it doesn't, go to the [official help forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube) and give them the following information:

- Your channel URL
- What you're trying to do (in this case: Log in)
- The full error message, ie the full block of the "random" numbers and letters **as text** (not as screenshot).